# Infinite sum upper bounds

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, inequality

Take the function and infinite sum

$f(n) = \frac{2n\choose{n}}{4^n(2n+1)}$

$\sum^\infty_{n=0}f(n) = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Given some $b$ I'd like to find $a$ such that $\sum^\infty_{n=a}f(n) < b$

It's clear that such a $a$ must exist as the series converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

An equivalent question is: Given some $b$ find $a$ such that $\sum^a_{n=0}f(n) \geq \frac{\pi}{2} - b$

What techniques might be used to find $a$?

Comment: Use Stirlings approximation to show $\frac 1 {4^n}\binom {2n}n\sim\frac 1 {\sqrt {\pi n}}$ and approximate the residual sum by an integral.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient if more accuracy is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I see two obvious options:
1) if $a$ is under, say, $10^9$ then you can compute your finite sum exactly. Or, you could compute the partial sums up to this limit and check to see if your condition is satisfied.
2) Use the Euler-Maclaurin formula to approximate the sum (this is likely much more efficient but requires a higher understanding of math).